# mysql updated_at use milliseconds since EPOCH as default ON UPDATE

Tags: mysql, datetime, sequelize.js, milliseconds

In my app I am using Sequelize. Now I want to use milliseconds since EPOCH for the updated_at column, so that it looks like:

```
-------------
updated_at
-------------
1571838511364
-------------
```

The data definition now looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
   `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `description` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
   `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I have done this to the `created_at` as it is easy to set the default value with Sequelize, but for `updated_at`, how do I set the default value for `ON UPDATE`?

I know 
`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp())` will give me the current millisecond, so I have:

```
updatedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.literal(
        'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp()) ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp())'
      ),
    },
```

And this will give me error:

```
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `ab`.`projects` 
CHANGE COLUMN `updated_at` `updated_at` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp()) ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp()) ;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp()) ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp()' at line 2
```

I also tried default value to be:
`'UNIX_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP'`
but I got the same sql error anyway.

How do I achieve my goal so that `ON UPDATE` will use the current millisecond value?

Comment: You can't set unix_timestamp as default. See if you really need a default value.

Comment: @nbkI realized that, but for `ON UPDATE` how can I not provide a default value?

Comment: by setting unix_timestamp in your code. or use tiimstamp or datetimpe  instead of vaarchar and when you select the column use unix_timestamp.

Comment: which version of mysql ?

Comment: can you run `show create table ab.projects` , on the bale before adding the new column ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 mysql8. I have updated  the question to show the table structure now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default value in mysql must a be literal  , only exception is using  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() .

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-types-defaults-explicit

`unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())` is different than `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

If you want milli-seconds or microsecond you must add a precision to `datetime` and `current_timestamp` .

You table will become this with a precision of 4 digits .

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
   `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `description` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
   `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `created_at` datetime(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(4),
   `updated_at` datetime(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(4) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(4),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4  ;
```

A example with sqlfiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a85ff/1 )